# Por que objeto no contiene una definicion para 'field'?

Tags: c#

Tengo una definicion de clase Pedido:

```
namespace Pizzeria.Models
     {
         public class Pedido
         {
             public int idPedido { get; set; }
             public int pizza { get; set; }
             public int cantidad { get; set; }
             public double cuenta { get; set; }        
         }
     }
```

Luego, estoy tratando de hacer un controlador API para agregar un pedido, con el siguiente código:

```
[Http Post]
     public IActionResult Crear (Pedido myPedido){
         PedidoService.AddPedido(miPedido);
         return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Create), new Object {Id = myPedido.idPedido }, myPedido);
     }
```

donde el método CreatedAtAction tiene que devolver un objeto. Pero el problema es que el compilador de C# dice que "El objeto no contiene una definición para Id".
¿Alguien sabe qué es esto y cómo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un Object es el elemento base de todos las clases, todos los objetos derivan desde Object. En tu caso, el objeto myPedido es Object, pero Object no es un objeto del tipo Pedido.

Object no contiene ninguna propiedad Id, ni ninguna otra. Por eso tu error.

Por otro lado, el método CreatedAtAction cuando recibe 3 parámetros, el segundo parámetro se refiere a las routesValues, que viene siendo los datos que van en la URL, no el objeto en cuestión (que es en el body del POST, el cual es el 3er parametro)

Prueba colocar:

```
CreatedAtAction(nameof(Create), myPedido)
```

o

```
CreatedAtAction(nameof(Create), null, myPedido)
```

Comment: Gracias. Tenias razon. Con null se resuelve. Estoy entrando en el mundo de las APIs. Gracias!!!